# Is it possibe to call multiple numbers (having a group call) with tel-hyperlink?

Tags: javascript, html, hyperlink

this one should be a real short question:

Is there a possibility to have a group call/call multiple numbers with using a tel: hyperlink?

The only way I see right now to solve this problem is to pre-define groups in for example skype and make a hyperlink to call the skype group. But is there another way around (preferred to do it with phone numbers)

Best regards & thanks in advance

Furkan

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible. Probably because phones can only call one number at the time.